# .NET MVC 3 Custom Controller Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This may be pie in the sky but I'm wondering if the following could be accomplished with a custom controller attribute.

For a majority of my controllers, I will be passing in an URL parameter called "r" to each action within the controller. "r" is tied to a race id in the races table in my database.

What I would like to happen is that any time a controller action is invoked, it'll automatically check for the existence of "r", query the database to make sure "r" belongs to the logged in user and set a viewbag variable called ViewBag.RaceId equal to "r".

If any of those conditions aren't met, it'll redirect them back to the login page.

I'm trying to make my code as DRY as possible.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a custom `Authorize` attribute:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (isAuthorized)
        {
            var request = httpContext.Request;
            // Fetch "r" from the route data or request
            var r = request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["r"] 
                ?? request["r"];
            var currentUser = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            if (!CheckIfRBelongsToTheCurrentLoggedInUser(currentUser, r))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return isAuthorized;
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is to decorate your controllers/actions with this custom attribute:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    //...
}
```

And if you wanted to put something into the ViewBag you could temporarily store it in the `httpContext.Items` inside the `AuthorizeCore` method in case of success and then override the `OnAuthorization` method as well and check for the presence of this item in the context. If it is present you could store it in the `filterContext.Controller.ViewBag`.

Comment: Pure Awesome. One question though regarding the ViewBag. In my custom attribute I added: httpContext.Items.Add("RaceId", r.ToString()); and in my override for OnAuthorization I added  filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.RaceId = filterContext.HttpContext.Items["RaceId"]; is that correct? New to overriding OnAuthorization.

Comment: Nevermind. I had ilterContext.Controller.ViewBag.RaceId = filterContext.HttpContext.Items["RaceId"] before  base.OnAuthorization(filterContext); It works now!

Comment: Note anyone who's using Darin's suggestion to pass data through `httpContext.Items`: you need to have `OnAuthorization` call `base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)` before checking `httpContext.Items`.   I couldn't get it to work until I did this.