# Same code for each mvc actionresult in home controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have some generic actionresults that link to various views for the time being. The layout page contains a call to adfs to populate a logged in user name that has to be for each page. Looks like this:

```
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                   Hello, <span class="username">@ViewBag.GivenName @ViewBag.LastName</span>!
                </section>
            </div>
```

In the home controller, what makes this logged in name work is this code here:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        Claim claimGivenName = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("http://sts.msft.net/user/FirstName");
        Claim claimLastName = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("http://sts.msft.net/user/LastName");

        if (claimGivenName == null || claimLastName == null)
        {
            ViewBag.GivenName = "#FAIL";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.GivenName = claimGivenName.Value;
            ViewBag.LastName = claimLastName.Value;
        }


        return View();
    }
```

But as mentioned earlier, I need this to display when a user goes to each link (actionresult). Therefore, I am having to post all the code above into each actionresult in order to achieve this.

Is there some way I can have this apply to each actionresult as a whole rather than having to duplicate code from one action to another? I did try just to register into an actionresult for my _Layout.cshtml and make the call to that partialview, but that didn't give me favorable results. I am sure it is something simple that I am missing.

Hoping some of you can help. Thanks much.

Comment: @Mark...is each ActionResult in the same Controller class?

Comment: It is all in the same controller class. For now anyway. May revise later. Is there a different answer for both ways?

Comment: @Mark Yes, if all your actions are in one controller, simply override the `OnActionExecuting` method of that controller. Otherwise, you need to consider base controllers or attributes.

Answer (score 1):

We use an abstract controller and override its `OnActionExecuting` method to execute code before the actual action method gets invoked. With this abstract controller, all you have to do is make any other controllers inherit from it to gain it's functionality. We also use this base controller as a place to define other helper methods that other controllers which extend it can use, such as `GetUsernameForAuthenticatedUser()`.

```
public abstract class AbstractAuthenticationController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationService _authService;

    protected AbstractAuthenticationController()
    {
        _authService = AuthenticationServiceFactory.Create();
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        EnsureUserIsAuthenticated();
    }

    internal void EnsureUserIsAuthenticated()
    {
        if (!_authService.IsUserAuthenticated())
        {
            _authService.Login();
        }
    }

    protected string GetUsernameForAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        var identityName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        var username = _authService.GetUsername(identityName);
        if (username == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No Username for " + identityName);
        return username;
    }
}
```

This functionality could also be implemented in an `Attribute` class which allows you to decorate your controllers as opposed to using inheritance but the end result is the same. [Here is an example of a custom controller attribute implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995607).

Comment: So then I could just add the code I needed in it's own .cs file, then reference in my home controller as public class HomeController : HelperController and it will automatically take the code and use it in that controller? So in each actionresult, I wouldn't actually need the code noted above since it would be in that class that I am inheriting from?

Comment: @Mark Yes, that is correct. Also, if you want to stop using `ViewBag`, this solution will allow you define Properties/Methods for `GivenName` and `LastName` which you could then use as you populate a `ViewModel` for your view. The only reason that approach is better than using the `ViewBag` is because then your values can be strongly-typed. Notice how we provide a way for child controllers to access the user's Username... that is so we can put it into a `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base controller and make all the controllers inherit from it. Move the code that sets the given and last names into a separate, protected method and call it whenever you need. I think you could call the function in the `Initialize` method of the base controller.  This way you won't need to call it directly into the actions.
You could also make a hierarchy of models and have `GivenName` and `LastName` as properties on the base model, instead of working with the `ViewBag`.

Comment: The above won't work because this is called through ADFS and there is no model for which to pull this data. Without going with a base controller, what are other options?

Comment: I was thinking to create and populate your model with the data that you already got from `ADFS`, but this is beside the point. As Jesse Webb mentioned, you could execute the code in `OnActionExecuting` method in your own controller and this won't require inheriting a base controller.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to using `OnActionExecuting` as this is just for a set part of the template would be to give it its own action method that returns a partial and call `@Html.Action()`